# How to "connect" 2 variables in Angular by some value

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 variables in controller:

```
$scope.first = [
    { id="11",  nameF="aaaa1" }, 
    { id="12",  nameF="bbbb1" }
]

$scope.second = [
    { id="21",  nameS="aaaa2", idFirst="11" }, 
    { id="22",  nameS="bbbb2", idFirst="12" }, 
    { id="23",  nameS="cccc2", idFirst="12" }
]
```

In a template I have ngRepeat for variable second:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in second>
    <div>{{item.nameS}}</div>
    <div>{{item.idFirst}}</div>
</div>
```

For every item.idFirst I would like to write out matching nameF instead. What is the best practice to achieve that? I can't seem to figure out a simple way to do it, but suppose there has to be one. Thanx!

Comment: I think you should change your model so that you don't have to do a database join in your Angular code.

Comment: I tought about it, but that isn't a good solution for this project - I would have too much "double" data accross models (more or less every model mathes 1 table in db)

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) if you don't want to create one single object holding the expected structure.

HTML :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in second">
    <div>{{item.nameS}}</div>
    <div>{{item.idFirst | getMatchName:first}}</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
.filter('getMatchName', function() {

          return function(strName, arrFirst) {

            arrFirst.forEach(function(val, key) {

              if (val.id == strName) {
                strName = val.nameF;
              }

            })

            return strName;
          }
        })
```

Here is working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Qr9r2mKBkmjJ78f2cBLq?p=preview)

Comment: It is actually almost the same as what @scokmen wrote, just with filter instead of a "normal" function. Since he wrote his post first, I will accept his answer. And give +1 to yours. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @ljerka it is not almost the same,You can use filter a part of ng-repeat syntax and it is called twice and not on each iteration which is the case as the above anwer

Comment: In the end I decided on using your solution, it really works the best - it is fast and works like a charm. With the solution from @scokmen I had some problems - "preparing" data was too slow so I often got undefined variables, and the first way was unecceptable because I had to have variable idFirst unchanged (for editing and saving purposes). So I changed the accepted answer to yours.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly,

```
$scope.getNameF = function(idFirst){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.first.length; i++){
        if($scope.first[i].id === idFirst){
            return $scope.first[i].nameF;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

<div ng-repeat="item in second">
  <div>{{item.nameS}}</div>
  <div>{{getNameF(item.idFirst)}}</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Also you can prepare data before rendering:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.second.length; i++){
    $scope.second[i].nameF = getNameF($scope.second[i].idFirst);
}

<div ng-repeat="item in second">
  <div>{{item.nameS}}</div>
  <div>{{item.nameF}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, actually that is exactly what came to my mind first. But I was hoping I can avoid loop for every repeat.

Comment: Isn't preparing them by loop more or less the same as looping during ngRepeat?

Comment: Yes but function call on ng-repeat is not good for performance in angularjs.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32624514/4841119

Comment: Good to know. Thanx.

Answer (score -1):

You can think of your template logic a bit like code, calling values from other variables: `yourValue[another.value].nameF`

Change your code to this and it should work

```
<div ng-repeat="item in second>
  <div>{{item.nameS}}</div>
  <div>{{first[item.idFirst].nameF}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried, but I get no result (it writes out blank). Although, I don't understand how can first[item.idFirst] writeout first.nameF? I also tried first[item.idFirst].nameF. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't first[item.idFirst] write out the item in first that is on the item.idFirst+1 place? Like array[2], for instance?

Comment: @ljerka Sorry there was an error in my example as it was done in a hurry. Edited my example. Of course you need to call it like this: first[item.idFirst].nameF

Comment: As I wrote, I tried it like that too, but it would still write out nothing.